# Apt-get update getting stuck at 0% while connecting to repository

Tags: apt

I installed a new Ubuntu on Hyper-V. Since I changed IP address, when I put in console `apt-get update`, it shows me:

```
0% [Connecting to de.archive.ubuntu.com (141.30.62.23)] 
[Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.24
```

and it's stuck at this. I disabled IPv6 and ufw. What else can I try?

Comment: Is this a question about apt? Or is this a question about networking?

Comment: @user535733 about apt-get update

Comment: Do you have internet connectivity i.e. are you able to browse the internet from your Ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: @AshishKumar I cannot ping websites but i can ping my hosts. I checked DNS. I typed 8.8.8.8. Its server version

Comment: @sphtd seems you have a network connectivity issue. make sure your network is setup properly

Comment: # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.3.22
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.8
dns-nameservers 192.168.3.6

What is wrong with dns?

Answer (score 1):

I had a wrong configyration of network. I put bad dns server

Comment: It would be great if you can just expand your answer and explain what you exactly did.

Comment: I used wrong address DNS

Comment: And how did you changed that? Please include that in your answer.